# Receive video+audio with pipeline

Tags: c++, pipeline, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

My PIPELINE-DESCRIPTION only video works:

```
"rtspsrc protocols=tcp location=" + urlStream_ + " latency=300 ! decodebin3 ! autovideosink ! autoaudiosink";
```

But...
I would like receive video+audio. I only receive it on the first frame and no audio:

```
"rtspsrc protocols=tcp location=" + urlStream_ + " latency=300 ! decodebin3 ! autovideosink ! autoaudiosink";
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to connect the `autoaudiosink` the the `decodebin3`. Currently you are *connecting* the sink to the video sink - which obviously is bogus.

It it also advised to use a `queue` after each demuxer pad. Try:

```
"rtspsrc protocols=tcp location=" + urlStream_ + " latency=300 ! decodebin3 name=decodebin ! queue ! autovideosink decodebin. ! queue ! autoaudiosink";
```

Comment: the video is still frozen and no audio